# Access directory in docker command "docker run -v $(pwd):/app rasa/rasa:1.10.8-full init --no-prompt"?

Tags: docker, rasa

I tried running below command:
docker run -v $(pwd):/app rasa/rasa:1.10.8-full init --no-prompt

Afte docker command execution I am getting message "Your Rasa model is trained and saved at '/app/models/20200721-095408.tar.gz'." but I am not able to access app folder.
Can anyone please guide me how can I access that directory.
I am new to Docker so please pardon me if I have asked a silly question.

Answer (score 0):

The `/app` directory is on the container itself. The volume mapping tells you the relationship between your file system and the container's:

```
-v $(pwd):/app
```

So you are mounting `$(pwd)` (your current directory) to `/app`. That means when it says that it saved it to the `/app/models` folder, this should have been mapped back to your existing filesystem, which would allow you to find the model in the `$(pwd)/models` folder.